# Is it possible to log into Gitlabs container registry without using the CI runner?

Tags: docker, deployment, gitlab

Is it possible to log into the Gitlab registry automatically from a script outside of the context of their CI runner?

I have a very simple deployment process with a home-baked script which does the following in a nutshell:

- build container image
- push to registry.gitlab.com
- log into the target server
- pull the container image from registry.gitlab.com
- run the container

Each interaction with Gitlab's registry requires the following:

```
docker login registry.gitlab.com
```

which will prompt for my username / password. I would prefer to be able to do something like this:

```
docker login -u <username> -p <password> registry.gitlab.com
```

so that I can achieve true automation of my deployments.

I've looked at Gitlab's documentation and spent some time searching on Google but all references I've found relate to using Gitlab's CI runner, which I do not need for my use-case.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Comment: [`docker login` supports those options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/).

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the pointer. I tried that but it doesn't appear to work with gitlab's registry authentication system

Comment: @Matt correction, it does work. I had a typo in the registry url. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely!
When you do a `docker login your.docker.registry.com`, what happens is:

- Your machine attempts to log in to the docker registry specified
- If login is successful, it creates a file at `$HOME/.docker/config.json`

This is outlined in the official docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/).

The `config.json` is a pretty easy to understand and pretty easy to echo in a shell script. Once you've logged in successfully, you can view your generated `config.json`.

Essentially this means you can execute something like this in a bash script:

`echo '{"auths":{"registry.gitlab.com":{"auth":"base64encodedcredentials"}}}' > ~/.docker/config.json`

Once the machine has this file in the right location, it shouldn't prompt you for a login or password when pulling images.

Just remember that **your username and password are stored in this file in a base64 encoded format**. You may want another set of dedicated credentials if this bothers you.